# JSON.parse invalid character

Tags: json, breeze, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I'm getting the Invalid Character error at line 12565 of Breeze 1.1.2's breeze.debug.js. The line is:

```
var metadata = JSON.parse(data);
```

I've researched this error message and the best suggestions I've seen are having unescaped single or double quotes, or invalid characters. But, I can't find either in the response.

I'm using BreezeJS to make the request and process the response. The response is being generated by Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider.Metadata(). I'm using IE11 on Windows 8.1. The server generating the response is IIS Express 8. I captured the request and response with Fiddler.

Can anyone see what's wrong with the response?

Request:

```
GET http://localhost/RisingTide.API/breeze/scheduledpayments/Metadata HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost/RisingTide.Web/#/scheduledpayments
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 862
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 15 Sep 2013 03:37:14 GMT

{"schema":{"namespace":"RisingTide.API.Models","alias":"Self","d4p1:UseStrongSpatialTypes":"false","xmlns:d4p1":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation","xmlns":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm","cSpaceOSpaceMapping":"[[\"RisingTide.API.Models.ScheduledPayment\",\"RisingTide.API.Models.ScheduledPayment\"]]","entityType":{"name":"ScheduledPayment","key":{"propertyRef":{"name":"Id"}},"property":[{"name":"Id","type":"Edm.Int32","nullable":"false","d4p1:StoreGeneratedPattern":"Identity"},{"name":"Description","type":"Edm.String","fixedLength":"false","maxLength":"4000","unicode":"true","nullable":"true"},{"name":"Amount","type":"Edm.Decimal","precision":"18","scale":"2","nullable":"false"}]},"entityContainer":{"name":"ScheduledPaymentsDbContext","entitySet":{"name":"ScheduledPayments","entityType":"Self.ScheduledPayment"}}}}
```

Comment: I'd like to see how BreezeJS is actually handling the response. I've got a hunch that "data" might have already been parsed by BreezeJS and is a JavaScript object, not a string. What do you get when you do console.log(data)?

Comment: I second Adam, could you screenshot `console.log(data)`? JSON.parse wont work if object keys have colon. But the site http://learn.breezejs.com/ seems to parse this http://learn.breezejs.com/api/northwind/Employees GET request quite easily...

Comment: Adam, naveen, you're right, data is already an object. Console.log(data) gives "undefined", while console.log(data.schema.alias) gives "Self". Any ideas what's triggered this? I'm guessing something I've done, like my use of metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor

Comment: I looked at some newer versions of Breeze.debug.js and at some point they changed the line to `var metadata = typeof (data) === "string" ? JSON.parse(data) : data;`. I'll upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze v1.1.2 is pretty old.  We fixed a number of bugs like this in earlier versions.  The latest current stable release is 1.4.2

Comment: I'll credit this as the correct answer, with a note that I had 2 projects - my server project is using Breeze 1.3.6 and my client project is using 1.1.2. I'm sure that mix didn't help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JSON.parse is getting tripped up over the `\"`.  It does not seem like JSON supports that.

```
"[[\"RisingTide.API.Models.ScheduledPayment\",\"RisingTide.API.Models.ScheduledPayment\"]]"
```

The quotes must be double backslashed, like this:

```
"[[\\"RisingTide.API.Models.ScheduledPayment\\",\\"RisingTide.API.Models.ScheduledPayment\\"]]"
```

It must be that \" is treated as a " inside of the "", but \" is treated as a \" inside the "".

Interesting. I didn't know that until I tried it. :-)

---

**UPDATE:** This screenshot of a session with CDT should help explain what is going on a bit better:

[image: Need double backslash for using quotes in JSON]

You can see that when you use a single backslash, the JSON will be paring `"""`, which is not a valid JSON string. But with \, JSON will be parsing a \ and 3 "s, which is valid.